# Saving data to Excel/PDF from VC++ MFC application

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I have written an ERP application wherein the user wants to save few reports directly to Excel and PDF. Right now I'm displaying the reports in List Control, which has to be saved to spreadsheet or PDF. I've written the application in VC++ MFC with Visual Studio 2005. Please help me how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

- To create PDF files I'd recommend
  [libHARU](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/230049). It's excellent - fast
  and easy to use.
- For Excel files manipulation please see: [How to
  automate Excel from MFC and Visual
  C++ 2005](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308407).